# How do I figure out which inputs to remove in outlier detection?

Tags: python, outliers, shap

I have a dataset which has ~60 columns and ~75000 rows. I used the isolation forest model to detect some outliers and do the shap plot to see the top features of these outliers.

My goal is : Not just detect the anomalous data but also figure out which inputs to remove.

I wonder are there any ways I can try to achieve my goal? I was thinking of using shap values as threshold for removing the inputs, but I don't know how to apply this thought. Hope you can give me some suggestions and solutions. Thank you!

Comment: This is not really a programming question. Your post would likely be better received on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

To detect outliers, there is a lot of machine learning lib such a famouse SKLearn.

To detect outliers and find which columns(features) contributed to the outliers, I only noticed that pyod could do it.
A copula based outlier detection algorithm could find outlier  as well as explain_outliers.

Here is the reference page:

https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyod/models/copod.html

Good luck.

vote the answer, if you like it.

Best Regards,
WangYong